# Is there a way to view the latest questions from sites to which I am subscribed?

Tags: support

I am new to StackExchange...

I registered on different sites but it is tedious to go check each one of them.

Is there that I can get a feed with the latest questions from the sites where I am subscribed just like quora.com does it?

Comment: This is weird. Are you sure that you'll be interested in **all** of the newest questions of one SE site?

Answer (score 3):

Not possible, but you can create a filter by going to https://stackexchange.com/filters/new and select the sites you want.

> [image]

Then this filter will be accessible in the sidebar of https://stackexchange.com/filters:

> [image]

Later, you can add more sites by clicking "edit" after the filter name.